# NameFor generates incorrect name when iterating over collection in editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose I have a view typed to a collection, e.g. a `List<ItemViewModel>`:

```
@model List<ItemViewModel>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Bar)
}
```

`Foo` and `Bar` are simply string properties.

This generates HTML name attributes of the form `[i].Foo` and `[i].Bar`, which, of course, is correct and binds correctly when posted in a form.

Now suppose, instead, that the above view is an editor template, which is rendered like so (where `Model.Items` is a `List<ItemViewModel>`):

```
@model WrappingViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
```

All of a sudden, the names generated within the editor template are of the form - for example - `Items.[i].Foo`. The default model binder can't bind this as it expects the form `Items[i].Foo`.

This works fine in the first scenario - where the view is not an editor template - and also works fine where the collection is a property, rather than the entire model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items[i].Foo)
```

It only fails when the model itself is a collection *and* the view is an editor template.

There are a few ways of working around this, none of which are ideal:

- Type the editor template to an individual instance of `ItemViewModel` - this is no good as the actual template in question contains additional markup for adding to/removing from the collection. I need to be able to work with the entire collection inside the template.
- Wrap the `List<ItemViewModel>` in another property (e.g. by implementing `ItemListViewModel`) and pass that to the template - this is not ideal, either, as this is an enterprise application that I would rather not clutter with superfluous wrapping view models.
- Generate the markup for the inner editor templates manually to produce the correct name - this is what I am currently doing but I would rather avoid it as I lose the flexibility of HtmlHelpers.

So, the question: Why does `NameFor` (and therefore `EditorFor`) exhibit this behaviour in this particular scenario when it works fine for slight variations (i.e. is it intentional and, if so, why)? Is there a simple way of working around this behaviour without any of the shortcomings of the above?

As requested, full code to reproduce:

Models:

```
public class WrappingViewModel
{
    [UIHint("_ItemView")]
    public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public WrappingViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<ItemViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new WrappingViewModel();
    model.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel { Foo = "Foo1", Bar = "Bar1" });
    model.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel { Foo = "Foo2", Bar = "Bar2" });
    return View(model);
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model WrappingViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

_ItemView.cshtml (editor template):

```
@model List<ItemViewModel>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Foo)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Bar)
}
```

Name attributes for `Foo` and `Bar` inputs will be of the form `Model.[i].Property` and will not bind back when posted to an action method with the signature `ActionResult Index(WrappingViewModel)`. Note that, as mentioned above, this works fine if you iterate over `Items` in the main view *or* if you get rid of `WrappingViewModel`, make the top-level model a `List<ItemViewModel>` and iterate over `Model` directly. It only fails for this specific scenario.

Comment: Could you propose a source code of action for the second scenario? What parameters do you expect in action?

Comment: @AlexanderSimonov I'll post some source code for reproducing the problem a bit later on.

Comment: @AlexanderSimonov Full reproducible code posted, as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does `NameFor` (and therefore `EditorFor`) exhibit this behaviour in this particular scenario when it works fine for slight variations (i.e. is it intentional and, if so, why)?

It is a bug ([link](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/544)) and it will be fixed with release of ASP.NET MVC 5.

> Is there a simple way of working around this behaviour without any of the shortcomings of the above?

**Simple:**

1. Add `ItemViewModel.cshtml` editor template with following code:

   ```
   @model ItemViewModel
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Foo)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bar)
   ```
2. Remove `_ItemView.cshtml` editor template.
3. Remove `[UIHint("_ItemView")]` attribute from `WrappingViewModel`.

**A little bit harder:**

1. Add `ItemViewModel.cshtml` editor template (same as above).
2. Modify `_ItemView.cshtml`:

   ```
   @model List<ItemViewModel>

   @{
       string oldPrefix = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;

       try
       {
           ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Empty;

           for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
           {
               var item = Model[i];
               string itemPrefix = string.Format("{0}[{1}]", oldPrefix, i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
               @Html.EditorFor(m => item, null, itemPrefix)
           }
       }
       finally
       {
           ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = oldPrefix;
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**

In case if you don't want to add `ItemViewModel.cshtml` editor template for the *second* option then instead of `@Html.EditorFor(m => item, null, itemPrefix)` you have to write  something like that:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => item.Foo, null, Html.NameFor(m => item.Foo).ToString().Replace("item", itemPrefix))

@Html.EditorFor(m => item.Bar, null, Html.NameFor(m => item.Bar).ToString().Replace("item", itemPrefix))
```

*NOTE*: It's better to wrap that piece of code as extension method